# How to assign Studio flow to phone number in twilio programmatically(Java/Nodejs)

Tags: java, node.js, twilio

I am trying to assign Studio flow to my active phone number which I have purchased in Twilio. Is there any other way apart from the UI in which you go to phone number and select it manually as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIMaP.png)
I am trying to do it programmatically or via using an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the incomingCallHandling resource.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135027-Configure-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-to-Receive-and-Respond-to-Voice-Calls#h_8cbacde3-417b-4bfe-94de-3e04e0bbd155

Comment: I tried this it updates the CALL STATUS CHANGE field but i want to update A CALL COMES IN field

Comment: You can set any portion you want, just need to pass in the right key. The full docs are here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource look at the example, Update IncomingPhoneNumber to use a new Voice URL. You can get the voiceUrl from the Studio Trigger Widget (Webhook).